# Installing vsftp on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I ran the command below on my Linode Ubuntu. This leads me to believe that vsftpd should be running but there is no vsftpd folder in /etc/ and there is no vsfptd.conf either.

Was it installed in a different folder or ... ?

```
root@bla:/etc# apt-get install vsftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vsftpd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/141kB of archives.
After this operation, 471kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package vsftpd.
(Reading database ... 32857 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking vsftpd (from .../vsftpd_2.2.2-3ubuntu6_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up vsftpd (2.2.2-3ubuntu6) ...
vsftpd start/running, process 10749
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the package is installed with

```
dpkg -l vsftpd
```

Check the contents of the package (does Ubuntu have a /etc/vsftp directory, where does the Ubuntu package drop it's stuff) with:

```
dpkg -L vsftpd
```

Check whether it is actually running with

```
status vsftpd
```

and / or

```
ps -ef | grep ftp
```

Answer (score 1):

[vsftpd setup](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/06/ubuntu-vsftpd-ftp-service-server.html)

Comment: very good one link

Answer (score 1):

The vsftp.conf in Ubuntu is in the etc directory: /etc/vsftpd.conf